# Error "odbc driver does not support the requested properties" after 3 or 4 mins of inactivity

Tags: mysql, excel, vba, odbc

I'm writing an app in VBA that connects to a remote MySQL database.  The connection is successful and works fine, but if I don't perform a DB operation for a few minutes, then the next time I try I get the error message "odbc driver does not support the requested properties".

This is the connection string I'm using:

```
Driver={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver};Server=mysql1008.mochahost.com;Database=XXXXXXXXX;User=XXXXXXXXX;Password=XXXXXXXXX;
```

I've trawled the net for two days now and can't find anything that might help.

Any ideas?

TIA

Comment: odbc 3.41 seems very old so 15 Year s or so, try a new one https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/odbc/ of course . If you also  have an old Version of mysql you should test older versions too https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/c-odbc/